# How can i edit the json in python and save

Tags: python, django

I have the query set and on each object i have the field where json is stored like this

`qs = Student.objects.all()`

Now the every object  has field called `json_data` which contains the nested json dump of the some object. That json object is as follows:

```
        "id": 10,
        "subject_set": [
            {
                "number": "9a16b",
                "date": "2013-04-16",
                "id": 30,
                "book_set": [ … ],
                "statement_no": "dc393015"
            },
            { … },
            { … }
        ]
    },
    "status": "active"

}
```

Now i want to perform some filtering on that json on every subject the student has then delete which don't match the criteria , for all the students and then save that json over the original one. But i am not able to find how can i delete the elements from json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That json object is a dictionary.

```
d= {1:1,2:2,3:3}
print d
#{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
del(d[1])
#{2: 2, 3: 3}
```

You can use the normal dictionary functions to modify it.

```
subjects= parent_object['subject_set']
for i in list(subjects):
    if i['number'] in ('0000','0001'): #some subjects you want to delete
        subjects.remove(i)
```

Comment: The thing is how can i delete subject from the list of subjects where name matches something. can you me some example

Comment: thanks for that , how can i do the partial match like `if['name'] icontains math`

Comment: Suppose the i want to search on `number` like `if['number'] icontains a16` from my example data

Comment: you mean if 'a16' in i['number']:

Answer (score 0):

If your question about deleting elements from json.

```
In [1]: import simplejson
In [30]: h = '{"name":"earth", "status":"died"}'
In [32]: json = simplejson.loads(h)
In [34]: json
Out[34]: {'name': 'earth', 'status': 'died'}
In [35]: json.pop('status')
Out[35]: 'died'
In [36]: json
Out[36]: {'name': 'earth'}
```

likewise you can add, edit, delete elements. refer [this](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for more info.